# Basic Hibernate Caching Question

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, caching, ehcache

Does Hibernate use cache (second level or otherwise) if all I am doing is batch inserts?
No entities are being requested from the database, and no generators are used.
Also, would StatelessSession vs Session change the answer? What if I was using a Session with a JDBC batch size of 50? The cache I will be using is Ehcache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doe Hibernate use cache (second level or otherwise) if all I am doing is batch inserts?

Newly inserted Entities instances **are cached** in the L1 cache (the session-level cache) before they are flushed to the database (see the section [13. Batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)), hence the need to `flush` and `clear` your session regularly to prevent OOM.

> Also, would StatelessSession vs Session change the answer?

Yes. As written in section [13.3. The StatelessSession interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession) : *A `StatelessSession` has no persistence context associated with it and does not provide many of the higher-level life cycle semantics. In particular, **a stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level or query cache**.*

> What if I was using a Session with a JDBC batch size of 50?

This just means that you should `flush`/`clear` the session every 50 insert.